# How to use "while True", and "return False" and how to create a function for them

Tags: python-3.x

When someone enters an incorrect password I want to loop user input, but if they get it correct I want it to stop looping.

`return False` I need a function for return but I don't know where or what to make it as

````
while True:
    userInput = input("Pass:")
    if userInput == password: 
        print("Correct, welcome to Fahuk Console.")
        print("Type \"help\" for a list of commands.")
        userInput = input("-")
    else:
        print("Incorrect password.") ```
````

I want to be able to enter a correct password and not have it ask me again

Comment: read on `break` statement

Comment: Please supply all of your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`while` will continue to execute the code it's given until the condition placed after it is false or until `break` is used to immediately exit the loop.

Try this:

```
while input('Please enter your password:') != password:
    print('Incorrect password.')
print('Correct, welcome to Fahuk Console.')
# ...
```

Or if you want to use `while True`, this:

```
while True:
    if input('Please enter your password') == password:
        break
    print('Incorrect password.')
print('Correct, welcome to Fahuk Console.')
# ...
```

(When you store a real password, you shouldn't store the password itself, but instead a difficult-to-reverse hash of that password. You might `import hashlib` and then instead of comparing `input()` to the password, you might compare `hashlib.sha256(input()).hexdigest()` to the password's SHA-256 hash.)

Answer (score 1):

Use this code:

```py
while True:
    userInput = input("Pass:")
    if userInput == password: 
        print("Correct, welcome to Fahuk Console.")
        print("Type \"help\" for a list of commands.")
        userInput = input("-")
        break
    else:
        print("Incorrect password.")
```

Use the `break` keyword

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way would be to use a break condition. Loops iterate over a block of code until an expression is false. Since your expression is always true, break would need to be used to terminate the current iteration/loop.

````
   while True:
        userInput = input("Pass:")
        if userInput == password: 
            print("Correct, welcome to Fahuk Console.")
            print("Type \"help\" for a list of commands.")
            userInput = input("-")
            break
        else:
            print("Incorrect password.") ```
````

Comment: This answers is exactly the same as @martinii 's answer , plus the function part that the OP wanted is missing